# TStringList.CustomSort: Compare() with variables

Tags: algorithm, sorting, delphi, custom-sort

I am trying to custom sort a TStringList by a column in a .CSV file. My code below works (slowly, about 14 seconds for 200,000+ lines):

```
function Compare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;

    function ColStr(const Ch: Char; const S: String; First, Last: Integer): String;
    var
        p1, p2: Integer;

        function GetPos(const N: Integer; Start: Integer = 1): Integer;
        var
            I, Len, Count: Integer;
        begin
            Result := 0;
            Len := Length(S);
            if (Len = 0) or (Start > Len) or (N < 1) then Exit;

            Count := 0;
            for I := Start to Len do begin
                if S[I] = Ch then begin
                    Inc(Count);
                    if Count = N then begin
                        Result := I;
                        Exit;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;

    begin
        p1 := GetPos(4, 1); // 4 should be a variable
        p2 := GetPos(5, 1); // 5 should be a variable
        if Last = 0 then Result := Copy(S, p1 + 1, length(S)) else Result := Copy(S, p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1);
    end;

begin
    Result := AnsiCompareStr(ColStr(',', List[Index1], 0, 1), ColStr(',', List[Index2], 0, 1));
end;
```

What I would want to do is not have this hard-coded but (where commented "*should be a variable*" depending on which column to sort). I know I can't use:

```
function Form1.Compare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
```

for inserting variables, as I get the error:

> Incompatible types: 'method pointer and regular procedure'.

I have searched through SO looking for instances of this error but cannot find one that fits my question. I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

This has to be done with Delphi 7 and Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TStringList.CustomSort()` does not let you pass in extra parameters, and it does not accept class methods or anonymous procedures.  But, what it does do is pass the actual `TStringList` itself to the callback, so I would suggest deriving a new class from `TStringList` to add extra fields to it, and then you can access those fields inside the callback, eg:

```
type
  TMyStringList = class(TStringList)
  public
    Count1: Integer;
    Count2: Integer;
  end;

function Compare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
    ...
    p1 := GetPos(TMyStringList(List).Count1, 1);
    p2 := GetPos(TMyStringList(List).Count2, 1);
    ...
begin
  ...
end;

...

List := TMyStringList.Create;
// fill List ...
List.Count1 := ...;
List.Count2 := ...;
List.CustomSort(Compare);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is excellent and just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

So you are performing searching for k-th occurence of `Ch` and substring creation at **every** comparison.

You can optimize this process - before sorting make list/array of stringlists, created from every string, separated by needed character - use `DelimitedText`.

Inside `compare` function just work with this array and column numbers - sadly, you have to define them as global variables in current unit (for example, after `Form1: TForm1`)